# Storing list element address into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 data structures -

- list, and
- dictionary.

List holds a bunch of keys. Dictionary has those same keys. As for the value of each key, I want to store the address of corresponding element in the list. What would this achieve: For a key, I would lookup the dictionary if the key is present or not. If key is present, then get the address of that element in the list and fetch/pop/append that element.

My question:

What do I store in the dictionary as the `value` of each key using which I can get to that particular element in the list? Index of a key will change in the list. For example, I can pop an element out and insert it towards the end. So that makes the index of all the keys change in the dictionary. Hence, storing the absolute index is not what I want.

Example of the list, some operation on it and the resultant list.
L = ['1', '2', '3']

```
Add '4' to list:             L = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
Pop the last unused element: L = ['2', '3', '4']
Use the element '2':         L = ['3', '4', '2']
Pop the last unused element: L = ['4', '2']
Add '1' to the list:         L = ['4', '2', '1']
Add '5' to the list:         L = ['4', '2', '1', '5']
Use '2' from the list:       L = ['4', '1', '5', '2']
```

As you can see, the position of the elements are changing based on the operations performed. Using dictionary will help to avoid searching the list if I had the stored the address of the element in it.

Comment: Do you mean that for every key, you need to store the list position as the value?

Comment: According to your example, the address would also keep changing, so storing the address would not be a solution.
Please note list stores elements in consecutive memory locations, you cannot make the element `'2'` have the same memory location irrespective of the index.

Comment: I see. Is there nothing that I can keep in the dictionary which will correlate with the list elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
d = {'A': {'value': 'a', 'index': 0},
     'B': {'value': 'b', 'index': 1},
     'C': {'value': 'c', 'index': 2}}
l[d['B']['index']]
'B' # result!
```

**EDIT (see comment below)**

To create or update call this:

```
from collections import defaultdict as DefaultDict

def index_lookup(elements):
    result = DefaultDict(list)
    for index, key in enumerate(elements):
        result[key].append(index)
    return result

>>> l = ['e', 'l', 'e', 'm', 'e', 'n', 't', 's']
>>> index_lookup(l)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'e': [0, 2, 4], 'm': [3], 'l': [1], 'n': [5], 's': [7], 't': [6]})
>>> l.pop(2)
'e'
>>> index_lookup(l)
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'e': [0, 3], 'm': [2], 'l': [1], 'n': [4], 's': [6], 't': [5]})
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my question that index of a key will change in the list. For example, I can pop 5 out and insert it towards the end. So that makes the index of all the keys change in the dictionary. Hence, storing the absolute index is not what I want.

Comment: Ok, if I understand you correctly: The dictionary should be a lookup table for the indicies of the list elements? I've edited my post but it makes no sense for me... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

> Index of the list element.

You can store the index of the list element in the dictionary, and then use `list[index]` to get that element.

A sample code -

```
lst = [5,4,3,2,1]
dict = {}
for idx, val in enumerate(lst):
    dict[val] = idx
print(dict)
>> {5:0 ,4:1 ,3:2 ,2:3 ,1:4}
```

Retrieval code, assuming `n` is the number to retrieve -

```
if n in dict:
    list[dict[n]]
```

Comment: thx for the answer. I forgot to mention in my question that index of a key will change in the list. For example, I can pop 5 out and insert it towards the end. So that makes the index of all the keys change in the dictionary. Hence, storing the absolute index is not what I want. If possible, can u edit the question itself with this comment?

Comment: Also, can you explain the requirement a little more? Why can't you use dictionary alone, why do you need a list as well?

Comment: I want to be able to find the oldest unused element from the list. I can lookup the list element and bring to the top of the list.

Comment: i have updated the question with an example set. hope it's clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's not possible. TO achieve this, I need to create class objects and store IDs of the previous and next elements like we would do in the linked list.